# Taking screenshot of android application window

Tags: android, kotlin

Iam creating plugin for taking screenshot of android application window size not screen size and emulator size only application by using Intellij IDEA by using kotlin.
when ever import below line of code
import androidx.test.espresso.screenshot.captureToBitmap

getting error. What should i do

In build.gradle file some dependency are included but not resolve the issue.
how to reslove the issue

Comment: Please post the full error message and stack trace, just writing "getting error" isn't helpful for other users reading your question.

Comment: Post your error stack-track so we can understand your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.